# Automatic text replacement [substitution], space to replace

Tags: shortcut

It seems that to replace text (Prefs/Keyboard Shortcuts/Text), one has to type a space after the keyword, and this inserts a space after the replacement text. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you have the global pref & also the prefs in each app...

Bear in mind there are 2 ways to trigger it - whether you have "Correct spelling automatically" set or not

Of course, you need Text replacement on, in for instance, Safari > Edit > Substitutions

[image]

but then if you also have
Edit Menu > Spelling & Grammar > Check Spelling While Typing *and also* Check Spelling Automatically

[image]
then as you start to type a substitution, it will first auto-suggest underneath
[image]
As soon as it auto-suggests, you have 2 options...

- Hit  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  & it will auto-fill & add a space, or
- Hit  <kbd>↓</kbd>  then  <kbd>Enter ⌅</kbd>  & it will **not** leave a space

The real down-side of having it set like this is if you're not expecting it to correct something & it does, without you noticing.
Any slightly unusual word or spelling can get auto-corrected to a simpler... yet wrong one, if you don't proof-read.

Your friend Anny quickly becomes Any, for instance
[image]